# Not to update the recyclerview scrolling position when item is added or removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I am working with recycler view and I have a small problem.
So I have a list of products in the parent recyclerview1 but in this I have another recyclerview2 in the recyclerview1 as the end item.
I can add items from recyclerview2 to recyclerview1 however when I scroll to the bottom to add and the new item is added into the recyclerview1, the recyclerview1 is slightly scrolled to the bottom to accommodate new item on screen however I don't want it to move downwards however I can add more products to cart.

I am already using diffutil. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: So you have 2 recycler views, one nested inside the other at the bottom.  You're adding items to the first recycler, putting them above the 2nd recycler.  And doing so is scrolling the recycler view.  You want it to stay in a fixed position.  Is that correct?  If so-  why is the second recycler in the first?  You'd have a much easier time if it wasn't.

Comment: Seperate out second recyclerview and have both of them inside a scrollview or something